# C scope question

Tags: c, scope

Is the following code valid

```
int main(){
int * a = 0;
if ( !a ) {
    int b[500];
    a = b;
}

//do something with a, 
//has the array a is 
//pointing too gone out
//of scope and garbage
//or is it still fine?
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it is not, b has gone out of scope, accessing it (through the pointer) is undefined behavior.

Comment: No? He asks: "has the array a is pointing too[sic] gone out of scope". That definitely should be a yes.

Comment: @Charles: "Is the following code valid?" "No, it is ... undefined behavior".  Seems fine to me.

Comment: scope only matters for names -- for the space allocated (what `a` points to), what matters is the storage duration, which is the same in this case, but might not be in others.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Fair enough, it wasn't totally clear. I read the 'real' question as being in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

As it often happens, the question you are asking is not really about *scope*, but rather about *lifetime* of an object. The lifetime of `b` array object ends at the end of the `if` block and any attempts to access it after that lead to undefined behavior.

In fact, pedantically speaking, it is even more about `a` than about `b`: once the lifetime of `b` ends, the value of `a` becomes indeterminate. An attempt to "do something" that relies on the indeterminate value of a pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Its undefined behavior -- the stroage duration of an obect declared in an inner scope (such as *b* here) lasts up until the end of the block in which its declared.